# Combining @keyframes and transform scale

Tags: html, css, css-animations

When I load the page the box will have infinite keyframes of animation jumpin. Now I want the box to increase its scale when I hover it, but I cant seem to work it out. When I add the "hover" code it will only work once. I added "infinite" but still it wont work. but when I removed the keyframe the scale will work just fine the way I want it to be, but I want to combine keyframe and scale together.

https://jsfiddle.net/vucocsym/1/

```css
#tag1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  border-style: none;
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  animation: jumping 1s 1s ease infinite;
  transition: 2s;
}

#tag1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

@keyframes jumping {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(5px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="tag1">
  <h4>Hello there!</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) allows multiple functions set together, e.g.

```
transform: translateY(5px) scale(1.3);
```

However, if you want to trigger `scale(1.3)` only on `:hover`, then you need to set it on a different element, that can be either an inner or a wrapper element.

In the following example, there are three elements for center, scale and bounce.

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.scale {
  transition: 1s;
}

.scale:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

.bounce {
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  animation: jumping 1s 1s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes jumping {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(5px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="scale">
    <div class="bounce">Hello there, hover me!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```